# TF_lite Convert using integer-only quantization

Tags: python

```
import tensorflow as tf
saved_model_dir='D:/sfz/tf_sfz'
def representative_data_gen():
    for input_value in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_images).batch(1).take(100):
    yield [input_value]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
tflite_model_quant = converter.convert()`enter code here`
open("D:/sfz/tf_sfz/model25.tflite","wb").write(tflite_model_quant)
```

the train_images don't know what it is,I only know to select a part of the representative data, I don't know what to do next?The training data is JPG file and TXT file，They are in a folder, how do I make train_images?What type of train_images is it?Can you fix the code a little bit

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to be so strict on the way creating representative_data_gen. It just need to be a generator that yeild a single batch training image ie (1,224,224,3). However, it should some way mimic the domain of your training dataset. Therefore, ideally, the train_images is the generator you use to fetch for training and do some sampling from it. Another way for you self creating and easier to understand the intuition is

```
def representative_dataset_gen():
    for _ in range(50):
        batch = next(train_generator)
        img = np.expand_dims(batch[0],0).astype(np.float32)
        yield [img]
```

You just need to make sure yeild the 4 dimension at the end of the representative_data_gen.